# Android map v2 dragging listener

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

In my application I need map dragging listener, I have followed the below link:
[How can I handle map move end using Google Maps for Android V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702117/how-can-i-handle-map-move-end-using-google-maps-for-android-v2) But I do not get 100% reliable solution.however its work based on the camera listener. I did the following things:

1. the code works on whenever the camera zooming.
2. so I changed
       the code to zooming level ( if zoom level is increased or decreased
       I do not call my methods.)
3. but my function is called if not zooming level is not changed.

my need is How can I get reliable solution by using the camera listener? If any bug is raised regarding the issue on Google please share the link.

my code sample:

```
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                    if(previousZoomLevel != cameraPosition.zoom) {
                        Log.e("zooming * previousZoomLevel", ""
                                + cameraPosition.zoom + "   "
                                + previousZoomLevel);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.e("NOT zooming * previousZoomLevel", ""
                                + cameraPosition.zoom + "   "
                                + previousZoomLevel);
                                myMethod();
                    }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always save the zoom level at the end of the onCameraChange, otherwise you are always comparing to 0 and therefore it will always count as zoom.

Comment: in the myMethod() I do some operation, do not change the zoom level. so the camera listener called and the previous zoom equal to camera zoom, so that myMethod() is called twice. How do I prevent?